# swift lexical structure of multiline comment

Tags: swift

From what is written here:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html

**multiline-comment → /* multiline-comment-text */**

**comment-text-item → Any Unicode scalar value except U+000A or U+000D**

**multiline-comment-text → multiline-comment-text-item multiline-comment-text opt**

multiline-comment-text-item → multiline-comment

**multiline-comment-text-item → comment-text-item**

multiline-comment-text-item → Any Unicode scalar value except /* or */

It seems like these kinds of comments are valid:

/* /* */

/* */ */

But they are not (because of the support of nesting multiline comments).

Is it just me or there is a mistake in the document?

Thanks,

Comment: It’s just you. It says in the last line that an unbalanced multi line comment delimiter can’t go into a multi line comment.

Comment: @matt , thanks for your answer, but as far as I know every rule like (abc -> b) just defines one way to create abc.
for example if I write the rules:
line-break → U+000A and
line-break → U+000D
it means that line break can be built using any of the rules